# Exec multiple SQL commands in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm creating the following stored procedure that should find all elements in WebPages table that meet some requirements. First, I'm generating some SQL queries (dynamically):

```
DECLARE @SitesForScan TABLE
(
    command nvarchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @SitesForScan(command) 
SELECT ('SELECT TOP ' + convert(varchar(10),[Credits]) + 
        ' * FROM [WebPages] pages WHERE pages.[WebSites_Id] = ' + 
            convert(varchar(10),[Id])) as "commnad"
FROM [WebSites]
WHERE [Credits] > 0
```

After that, table variable `@SiteForScan` contains multiple SQL commands. Now, I want to execute each of those commands, combine all of the results they returning and return the results.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's possible that this can be realised as a single query that describes the entire operation, rather than using this current piece of code to generate more SQL and then running all of the SQL - could you provide some sample data and the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can Ues Dynamic SQL to `EXECUTE` YOUR SQL

```
DECLARE @SQL Nvarchar(MAX)=N'select * from @SitesForScan'

EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: Not solving the problem. My @SitesForScan table is containing lots of row that each one of them is a valid SQL statement. I'm want to execute each one of them and combine all the results together.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever can You Show Some of Your Raw data?? or Contents of table after insertion `@SitesForScan`

Comment: The return value of this SP should be the result rows that they are the output of the execution of each row from @SitesForScan.

Answer (score 0):

The below statement uses an identity column to tour @SitesForScan table so that we can use a while loop for executing all queries.

```
DECLARE @SitesForScan TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    command nvarchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @SitesForScan(command) 
    SELECT ('SELECT TOP ' + convert(varchar(10),[Credits]) + ' * FROM [WebPages] pages WHERE pages.[WebSites_Id] = ' + convert(varchar(10),[Id])) as "commnad"
        FROM [WebSites]
        WHERE [Credits] > 0

declare @i int=1,@sql nvarchar(max)=''
while (@i<=@@ROWCOUNT)
begin
set @sql=(select command from @SitesForScan where id=@i)

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
set @sql=''
set @i=@i+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at what you currently have, I think that the following would produce the results you're aiming for (once you fill in the blank):

```
;With Ordered as (
     SELECT wp.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY wp.Websites_Id
         ORDER BY --I don't know what column to put here
         ) as rn,
         ws.Credits
     FROM
         WebSites ws
            inner join
         WebPages wp
            on
                ws.Id = wp.Websites_Id
)
SELECT * from Ordered where rn <= Credits
```

At the moment, your query is non-deterministic in *which* rows from `WebSites` will be retrieved (because you use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`). If that's an essential part of the overall operation, let me know. Otherwise, put an actual column in where I have the `ORDER BY` in my query and you should get the results you want.